# Can one say "take an integral" instead of the usual "calculate an integral"? What other options are there?

Tags: integration

Russians often use the formulation "take an integral". Now I noticed it in an article, written by a Russian speaker and I can't recall I have ever encountered it in English. Is it a possible alternative to the basic "calculate an integral"? What other options are there? "Evaluate", "find", ...?

I have also asked this question on [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/608960/can-one-say-take-an-integral-instead-of-calculate-an-integral-what-other-op)

In the comments, I was rightfully asked for more context:

The thing is, Russian speakers use the formulation "take" (the integral) really in the sense of "calculate" (the integral) and not only in the sense of "consider" (the integral), which I feel is meant when English speakers use "take" in this context. E.g., Russian speakers say: "We will succeed to take the integral.". (У нас получиться взять этот интеграл.)

Comment: It’d help to have a couple more detailed examples.

Comment: Taking an integral seems more like something that happens before doing things that are best left unmentioned. ;)

Comment: I asked this question on [MESE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2288/446) a long time ago

Comment: @MatthewLeingang unfortunately, now we cannot vote to close this question as a duplicate to yours because this is math.stackexchange and you asked your question on matheducators.se.

Comment: I'm not saying the question should be closed as a duplicate to mine; I'm only adding it for context.

Comment: @littleO I've expanded the question for more context. I can update more, if things are still not clear enough.

Comment: I don't think it matters. It's just like asking "May I use the bathroom" vs. "Can I use the bathroom".

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered / used this. Roughly: "so, we have this expression... now take its integral to obtain ..."

We can evaluate an integral - this is probably the most formally correct. It's fair to say 'find' too; "compute", "calculate", "derive" (if there is a general result)...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some people, who say it roughly like:

"Now, take the integral", "Evaluate the value of I = {some integral}", "Calculate the value of this {some integral}", etc..

Comment: “Evaluate the value of...” sounds redundant, since *evaluate* and *value* have the same root.

Comment: Uhm yeah, I know that but you know, I was just thinking that one can ask in this way certainly